# grails assets dependsOn

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

In the old world of Grails 2.3X with resources, the actual resources could be defined in a specific order i.e. dependsOn

I have been looking around the assets notes:

https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin

I can not seem to find anything related to dependency since at the moment even though I have defined a specific script below another I am getting error that would be if it were started before it.

Comment: https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/96

Answer (score 0):

got this working in the end

```
//= require jquery/jquery
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-route/angular-route
//= require angular-resource/angular-resource.min
//= require angular-table/ng-table
//= require $app/index
//= require $app/services
//= require $app/arrestedDirectives
//= require_tree custom-$app
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
```

where the $app gets parsed replaced with users app (within a plugin - thanks baxxabit)